# Can I sync an iphone running OS 4 with a PC running iTunes 9.2

Tags: iphone, windows, itunes, synchronization, ios4

Just downloaded the iOS 4 GM seed from the apple developer site.  Apparently from what I've read, I can't install it unless I do a full restore of the Phone.  If anybody knows of a way to do it without restoring would be part of this question.  I normally sync all my music and stuff with my PC.  Will I be able to restore my device and resync up with my PC if the device has the iOS GM seed on it.  I have iTunes 9.2 on my PC.  Thanks!!

Comment: Not a programming-related question.

Comment: Not programming related. And actually a breach of contract if you are not a beta tester.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restore your device to install the iOS GM.

You **can not** install iOS4, or even use a device with iOS4GM on a PC, even if it has iTunes 9.2.

Comment: Couldn't you install iOS4 on the device using a mac and then restore from the PC?

Comment: No, I read an article about Windows and iOS 4. It said that any attempt to connect an iPhone with iOS4 to a Windows computer, would result in an error.